# Add alternate customer role to WordPress / WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add another customer role to WordPress and WooCommerce. I will use this new customer role to assign alternate prices when the user is logged in. My code works but I cannot find what permissions a customer has in WordPress / WooCommerce by default. I want this new role to have identical permissions to the default customer account. The code below is located in my child functions.php file.

```
/* Custom user roles */
add_role('distributor', __(
   'Distributor'),
   array(
       'read'            => true, // Allows a user to read
       'create_posts'      => true, // Allows user to create new posts
       'edit_posts'        => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
       'edit_others_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit others posts too
       'publish_posts' => true, // Allows the user to publish posts
       'manage_categories' => true, // Allows user to manage post categories
       )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the capabilies of another role and use this as the "capabilities array" when you create the new user role with the `add_role()` function of wordpress. I assume the role you want the capabilities to be copied over is called `customer`. You can adjust this.

```
add_role( 'distributor', 'Distributor', get_role( 'customer' )->capabilities );
```

The function accepts an array of capabilites. With `get_role()` you get an role object and access the capabilities of that role.

So we create a new role with the capabilities of an existing role.